# Convert Data table to Pivot data table c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, ini

I have data table in c# project as follows,

[image]

I want to pivot/convert this data table in following format,
[Expected format]

[image]

Where Section will become distinct rows.
Keys will become Columns and values will get added into appropriate keys.

Comment: I think this entry: https://techbrij.com/pivot-c-array-datatable-convert-column-to-row-linq can help you with your request. It's a general approach for converting `DataTable`s or `Array`s to "pivot".

Comment: @RedFox it has last item as number/int, in my case it is string only.            
 var pivotTable = data.ToPivotTable(
              item => item.Year, 
              item => item.Product,  
              items => items.Any() ? items.Sum(x=>x.Sales) : 0);

Comment: If you want non distinct values for the column names (e.g. Customer) you can not use a DataTable, because it would throw an `DuplicateNameException`. If you need the "same" column multiple times then you could number them consecutively. If you need distinct columns you have to define the value that should be selected in the `dataSelector`.